# Did 4 righteous caliphs take Jizyah from non Zoroastrian polytheists?

Tags: quran, hadith

Since Quran 9:29 says jizya can only be taken from ahle-kitaab do we have reference of righteous caliphs taking jizya from polytheists?

IslamQA doesn't considers Zoroastrians as polytheists coming under 9:5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sahih Muslim recorded a narration which said prophet instructed war commanders to take jizya from polytheists.

> It has been reported from Sulaiman b. Buraida through his father that when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) appointed anyone as leader of an army or detachment he would especially exhort him to fear Allah and to be good to the Muslims who were with him. He would say:
>   Fight in the name of Allah and in the way of Allah. Fight against those who disbelieve in Allah. Make a holy war, do not embezzle the spoils; do not break your pledge; and do not mutilate (the dead) bodies; do not kill the children. **When you meet your enemies who are polytheists**, invite them to three courses of action. If they respond to any one of these, you also accept it and withhold yourself from doing them any harm. Invite them to (accept) Islam; if they respond to you, accept it from them and desist from fighting against them. Then invite them to migrate from their lands to the land of the Muhajireen and inform them that, if they do so, they shall have all the privileges and obligations of the Muhajireen. If they refuse to migrate, tell them that they will have the status of Bedouin Muslims and will be subjected to the Commands of Allah like other Muslims, but they will not get any share from the spoils of war or Fai' except when they actually fight with the Muslims (against the disbelievers). If they refuse to accept Islam, **demand from them the Jizya**. If they agree to pay, accept it from them and hold off your hands. If they refuse to pay the tax, seek Allah's help and fight them. When you lay siege to a fort and the besieged appeal to you for protection in the name of Allah and His Prophet, do not accord to them the guarantee of Allah and His Prophet, but accord to them your own guarantee and the guarantee of your companions for it is a lesser sin that the security given by you or your companions be disregarded than that the security granted in the name of Allah and His Prophet be violated. When you besiege a fort and the besieged want you to let them out in accordance with Allah's Command, do not let them come out in accordance with His Command, but do so at your (own) command, for you do not know whether or not you will be able to carry out Allah's behest with regard to them

Attribution: https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/3

Even if its recorded that Rashidun didn't accept jizya from polytheists, we have narration informing us jizya to be taken from Polytheist from prophet.

We have another narration where Umar was not knowing about expelling disbelievers from Arabian peninsula, he acted immediately after coming to know about the hadith of prophet and expelled Jews from khaybar.

> Narrated Jabir bin ‘Abdullah :
>   "Umar bin Al-Khattab informed me that he heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: 'I will expel the Jews and the Christians from the Arabian Peninsula, and I will not leave anyone in it except a Muslim."
>   [Abu 'Eisa said:] This Hadith is Hasan Sahih.

Attribution: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/21/70

> Malik said that Ibn Shihab said, ''Umar ibn al-Khattab searched for information about that until he was absolutely convinced that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, had said, 'Two deens shall not co-exist in the Arabian Peninsula,' and he therefore expelled the jews from Khaybar."

Attribution: https://sunnah.com/malik/45

**Conclusion**:

If rashidun didn't accept Jizya from non pharsi polytheists, its a ijtihad on their part, some hadith might not have reached them.

Comment: "some hadith might not have reached them" - i think this might need some explanations, because these are the companions who was closest to the Prophet...

Comment: I have already given explanation in answer

Comment: The Arabian peninsula of the hadith is unlike the one we know of these days!

Comment: @medi1saif How is it relevant to my answer or question?

Comment: Because without this addition your answer is misleading!